# Swift - performSegueWithIdentifier in thread

Tags: swift, dispatch-async

i've got this type of problem :

With my app i'm able to connect my iPhone with a `BLE` device so when i connect their together i'm transported into an another view.
Into this view i've to check always if i'm connected yet in a thread func.
If my connection is lost i've to call the `performSegueWithIdentifier` method.
But... When i do it, xCode give me back a bad report that says :

> This application is modifying the autolayout engine from a background
>   thread, which can lead to engine corruption and weird crashes. This
>   will cause an exception in a future release.

This is my short code :

```
override func viewDidLoad(){
  super.ViewDidLoad()
  let priority = DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT
  dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(priority, 0)) {
    while(true){
      if(serial.connectedPeripheral == nil){
        self.GoBackToBLE()
      }
    }
  } 
}
```

I want to precise that i can't use the method `dispatch_get_main_queue` because if i use that i can't do anything else into the view for example if i have a button I want to be able to press it and if i use `dispatch_get_main_queue` method i can't.

any suggestions? thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't do anything related to UI in `dispatch_get_global_queue` 
you can split the things to run into 2 parts, 1 is related to UI other one is doing network calls/calculations etc.

```
override func viewDidLoad(){
  super.ViewDidLoad()
  let priority = DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT
  dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
    // do the ui stuff here
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0), { () -> Void in
      // do everything which is not ui
    })
  })
}
```

Comment: So if I have to change the view using the perform segue I have to put that method into the main_queue right?

Comment: yes, but what is in GoBackToBLE? you can split this function into 2 different functions.

Comment: Gobacktoble is only the function that I've tried to use for change view into this function there is only the prepare for segue method!

Comment: So than it should move to main_queue.

Comment: Thanks. This evening when I turn back to home I'll tell you if it works or not